# Use Spring bean on JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a spring bean with request scope

```
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component(value = "env")
public class MyAppContext
{
  // ...
```

And now I want to use it on JSP page with `jsp:useBean` tag.
Spring bound `MyAppContext` to request like `scopedTarget.env` attribute.
I tried to get it with

```
<jsp:useBean id="scopedTarget.env" type="com.soft.MyAppContext" scope="request" />
```

but it is unsuccessful because of dot in the id.
So my question is:
How can I change default attribute naming? (remove `scopedTarget` prefix)
Or how can I inject bean with dot in name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926664/accessing-data-from-session-scoped-beans-in-jsp-files this is for session but should work fo request too